# Flag window glitch?

Tags: discussion, support, flags

The flag window looks like it has a glitch:

[image: glitch]

I raised the "spam" flag, but not the "rude or abusive" flag, plus why would the last flag option still be available?

The spamy post was: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30389571/a-new-formula-to-shape-you-younger

Comment: There is a duplicate which explains this. I'm not good at finding those :-) Flags have different "types". Here you see three, Spam, Moderator and The Rest. Any flag from The Rest is said to be raised already once one of them has.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) and not a glitch. Both "spam" and "rude/abusive" flags go into the same mod queue because they are treat as being of **same type**. Since you can have only one active flag per post, so the system does not allow you to flag a post "rude/abusive" if you have already flagged it as "spam".

Comment: Fair enough answer. Thank you Aziz.